# Record Live Streaming

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, flash

Is it possible to record live streaming from websites such as Ustream or any other similar website using Adobe Flash Player?

I know that is possible to record the screen but the quality is not that good.

Any suggestions for any applications?

PS: I found that I can easily record Windows Media Streaming Videos or any other similar videos using VLC, easy and fast.

Answer (score 8):

I use a small command line utility called `rtmpsuck` which listens out for to a live stream (using the rtmp protocol) being played from your browser and saves it to your hard-drive.

- Install from Software Center `rtmpdump`
- Using Users & Groups create a user called `rtmp` - ensure to "Enable Account". I didn't want to see `rtmp` on my Logon Screen so in Advanced Settings - Advance tab I changed the new users UID to a unique number below 1000 i.e. in my case 998
- Redirect some live-streaming traffic for this new `rtmp` user

`sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1935 -m owner  \! --uid-owner rtmp  -j REDIRECT`

- Create a folder in your Downloads folder called `mysavestreams`
- Using Nautilus (File Manager) right-click this new folder and Share it - make sure the check-boxes are selected: "Share this folder", "Allow others to create and delete files in this folder", "Guest access (for people without a user account)"
- `cd ~/Downloads/mysavestreams`
- `sudo su rtmp`
- Now browse to your live-streaming site and find the live-stream playing
- `rtmpsuck`

This will record what you are seeing on the screen into a new file saved in `mysavestreams` folder.

It works for the vast majority of live-streaming sites - e.g. Justin.tv

However, it is a little ironic that the one site you've listed in your question doesn't work!  In these circumstances I would use `recordmydesktop` found in Software Center to capture the Stream being displayed on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has a plugin called Video Download helper that excels at just this task. It has a directory of sites that it works with, as well as smart naming for many of them: it looks at the title of the page and tries to name the video appropriately.

Once you install it, open the page with the video you want. The Download Helper icon will start dancing--then you just click to select which video you want from the menu next to it, and viola!

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/

Comment: Yes. But the problem is that I want to download/record **LIVE** streams.

Answer (score 1):

I found a few that may help you I'll list them below

- 1  Elisa

Elisa is a sort of Internet browser/media player mixed into one, which is useful if you access a lot of your media over the Web. You can play your own files as well as those found on the ’net. See Elisa’s homepage if you’re curious, or ElisaMediaCenter to learn how to install and run it on Ubuntu.

- 2 Streamtuner

Streamtuner is a stream directory browser. The idea is simple: Browse through internet streaming directories to locate radio stations or broadcasts you like, bookmark them and play them with your favorite media player. Streamtuner includes support for some of the largest directories and listings of internet radio stations and live broadcasts such as SHOUTcast, Live365, Xiph and basic.ch. With the help of an additional software package called streamripper, you can record your streams or live broadcasts and save them to your hard drive so you can listen to them at a later time. For more information, visit the Streamtuner web page.

- 3 gtk-recordMyDesktop

gtk-recordMyDesktop is a graphical frontend for recordMyDesktop that permits to record desktop sessions (audio and video sream) in ogg files.

of course VLC may help

- 4 VLC

VLC (formerly the VideoLAN Client) is a kind of Swiss Army knife of media players. It plays any file you can throw at it, audio or video; plays DVD’s and CD’s; boasts a variety of skins; and much more. To install VLC, just install the following package: vlc.

I hope one of these programs will do exactly what you need to do

Comment: Hello mate, Thanks for your list but I tested every single program and no one seems to do what we are looking for. The only relevant is number 3. We want a program to record live streaming from sites such as ustream, justintv etc.