# What capture card recording software is available?

Tags: installation, software-recommendation, capture

I'm trying to find good game capture software to use my climax digital vcap 303 with, the disc it came with didn't work (ArcSoft Showbiz)after downloading wine.

I have downloaded TVtime television Viewer but I can't seem to get it to work. The answers in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54787/record-live-streaming) didn't help.

Comment: you can record input streams using VLC, this may help you `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcHLWkx4gIU`

Comment: no that didnt help.

Comment: Please provide details. *Why* didn't it help? What did you try exactly, and what happened. So far, it's remains unclear if there is anything about this question that would make it possible to write an answer that applies to it but not to [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54787/record-live-streaming).