# Video recording software

Tags: software-recommendation, capture, video-recording

I run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I want to record output from a digital decoder to disk so that it can be watched later on.

Just to clarify the matter; instead of displaying, or while displaying, the output from the decoder on a TV screen, I want to record what is being output from the decoder in mp4 or avi format.

My question is: Does any software exist that will run on Ubuntu that will do the recording? What hardware will be have to be used with the software to enable the software to record the decoder's output?

What I am wanting to do is not the same as the question on "Record Live Streaming - cmks" which is streaming from a website. I'm wanting to record what a decoder is receiving from a satelite and sending to my tv via HDMI or RCA cables.

I found [this hardware on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=video+cpature&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xvideo+capture.TRS0&_nkw=video+capture&_sacat=0) that will most likely do the job. All the items are sold with software for Windows. I'd like to avoid using Windows.

Many thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Record Live Streaming](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54787/record-live-streaming)

Comment: What I am wanting to do is not the same as the question on "Record Live Streaming - cmks" which is streaming from a website. I'm wanting to record what a decoder is receiving from a satelite and sending to my tv via HDMI or RCA cables.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this myself, but I do have an old EasyCap branded usb capture device somewhere. Note that there are a few versions of these devices with different chip-sets. There is a good guide to identifying your device [on this site](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Easycap). An easy way to capture video in Ubuntu is VLC Media Player which is available in the Ubuntu repositories.
There are other options for capturing the video from these cards, it depends if you want to use [command line](http://easycap.blogspot.co.uk/p/command-line-tv.html) or [GUI](http://easycap.blogspot.co.uk/p/gui-tv.html) tools.

Comment: I am testing stk1160 and mplayer. Although the interface is not a GUI the video works very well. I'm working on getting the sound as well. Thanks you for your suggestion !